# 4g sim card dongle and resetting

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, remote, dongle, sim

I have a huawei e3372 4g/wifi dongle and I used it in combination with a mobile data sim card. I plug it into my computer and now I can surf the web using the 4g mobile data. I remote control this computer via Teamviewer, so I don't have physical access to it easily.

I want to use this sim card in order to get different IP addresses. If I remove the Huawei dongle and insert it back again, then I do get a new IP address. I want to be able to get a new IP address by remote controlling the computer via Teamviewer. So every time I have to ask my family member to remove the dongle and insert it back again. But if I turn off the connection from the dongle by going to control panel> network and internet > network and sharing center > change adapter settings > right click > disable and then enable again, then I don't get a new IP address. Also when I turn off the USB ports via device manager, I also don't get a new IP address. Also when I remotely restart the computer, then I also don't get a new IP address.

My question is, is there another way to get a new IP address that I can do via remote controlling this computer and not having to ask someone else to unplug and plug the USB dongle again?